# What mechanism Firefox uses to render it's Chrome and webpages?

Tags: windows, firefox, rendering, implementation

I'm interested in implementation details of Firefox's rendering engine on Windows, in particular (however would be interesting to know how it differs from Linux, too). I couldn't find any source code online in a brisk search, it seems there is no other way but to download it all locally. And, sadly, I don't even have that much time to dive into it and figure this out, so I'm asking here maybe someone can make a brief explanation?

I tested Firefox window with WinSpy, and its obvious that it's not using GDI or any other native Windows API, as it has no child windows, only single monolithic one. Is it using DirectX\OpenGL and renders text and everything on 2 polygons glued into rectangle?

Comment: Pretty sure it uses/used GDI on XP/Vista where there is no Direct2D.

Comment: The Firefox source code is publicly available online as a [mercurial repo](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/) and its [github mirror](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/) You can use [SearchFox](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/) to quickly search the codebase without downloading it.